# How to horizontally center a component while there are other components in the same row?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flexbox

I'm trying to mimic a stack navigation header like below: 
[image]

where the title is perfectly centered while there's a return button in the same row on the left.

I have tried to use `justifyContent: 'space-between'` with an empty `View` on the right side but the title will be off center to the right a bit. How should I approach this?

my `renderHeader` function:

```
  _renderHeader = () => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.headerAbsolute}>
        <View style={styles.bar}>
          <ButtonBack
            text={"Resumes"}
            onPress={() => this._onNavBackHandler()}
          />
          {true ? (
            <Text style={styles.headingFixed}>{this.state.title}</Text>
          ) : ( null )}
          <View/>
        </View>
      </View>
    )
  }
```

These are the styles:

```
  bar: {
    height: 55,
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: 'flex-end',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    paddingBottom: 5,
  },
  headingFixed: {
    fontSize: TITLE_TERTIARY,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    color: COLOR_DARK_SECONDARY,
    backgroundColor: 'transparent', 
  },
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I will make use of Flex here.
Please note that i used borderWidth in the below example only for reference to show how it looks.

I will have flexDirection as row and i will give a `flex: 1` to all the views inside

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text
}
from 'react-native';

class App extends Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <View>
        <View style={styles.navBar}>
          <View style={styles.itemStyle}>
            <Text style={{fontSize: 18, color: 'blue'}}>Resumes</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.itemStyle}>
            <Text style={{fontSize: 20, color: 'blue'}}>Settings</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.itemStyle}></View>
        </View>

      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = {
  navBar: {
    marginTop: 42,
    height: 36,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  itemStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    height: 36,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    borderWidth: 1
  }
}

export default App;
```

You can play around in the inside views. Move the buttonBack inside one of the child views.

[image: Comp]

Answer (score 3):

I can think of two ways to accomplish this, but neither seems quite ideal.

The first way is using a transparent element with fixed width and `justifyContent: 'space-between'`, as you indicated:

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
  <Text style={{width: 80}}>left</Text>
  <Text>center</Text>
  <Text style={{width: 80, color: 'transparent'}}>right</Text>
</View>
```

Setting a fixed width to the elements on each side will cause the middle element to center horizontally.

An alternative approach is using absolute styling. Using percentages with `left` and `right` requires React Native >= 0.42.

```
<View>
  <Text>Left</Text>
  <Text style={{position: 'absolute', width: 50, left: '50%', marginLeft: -25}}>Center</Text>
</View>
```